# How can we retreived most viewed videos per day using Youtube Data API?

Tags: python, api, youtube, youtube-data-api

I have been searching for the same on Youtube API Docs, but couldn't able to find out the same. It'll be very helpful if You guys can help me out, If that's possible.I want to find out is there any way we can find out how many views has a video per day. Like I want to know the most viewed videos today in Music Catergory. So I just want to know the most viewed videos by Genre per day.

Comment: You should explain what you've tried and not only add a question to the kind of code you'd like to have. 
There's some documentation for Google API, and aspects related to Youtube, as you can see: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started.
Take a closer look, try something, and then post the code here so we can help you with specific questions, @AdityaSharma

Comment: @LuanNaufal, As I said I tried searching and use some API in their API Explorer section but I couldn't find the one that I need so that's why I ask for a favor, nothing else.

Comment: Have you managed to get pass the auth process for Google API? In positive case,  which methods have you checked? What have you tried? Is not a matter of doing a favor, but it's the logic behind this community. We don't write code for other people.

Comment: I suggest for you to start looking for the the following examples and build something that can be posted here, with specific questions:
https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/search.py
https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/yt_analytics_report.py
https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/create_reporting_job.py
https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/retrieve_reports.py

Answer (score 1):

This is the latest trending youtube video api call
Chart = select most popular
RegionCode = enter where do you want

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id%2Csnippet%2CcontentDetails&chart=mostPopular&regionCode=IN&key={YOUR_API_KEY}